# Skype installation? Failure!

Tags: skype

I have been trying to install Skype for the terminal, I cant get past trying to give it a pass word. It will not even let me type one in. Good thing this computer is set to log-in automatically.

john@john-X55U:~$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-xml libasound2
[sudo] password for john:

using this one does the same thing: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32asound2 ia32-libs libc6-i386 lib32gcc1

I did get it to allow me to try too many pass words (this machine is borrowed from a friend), but then it decided I was trying to hack in, so it will not take a pass word at all now. Or so it seems.

When I try to install automatically, I keep getting a pop-up that says “this involves installing packages form unauthenticated sources”, then is give me the options of “repair”; I have to click that several times.
Then I get a notice that “new soft were can't be installed because there is a problem with the soft were already installed”. Do I need a newer version of Ubuntu? I do not know how old this one is.**

Comment: Note that `sudo` will not put anything on the screen as you type.

Comment: +1 to user4901968 for being able to decipher this.

Comment: Yes, so basically when you type a password in the terminal you don't actually see what you type. Just type the password carefully and press enter. Do you know the user's password, by the way? Because if not, you might aswell want to consider reinstalling from scratch :-) Or well, you can always try this  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Comment: HOW DO I DETERMINE WHAT VERSION OF UBUNTU IS ON THIS MACHINE?

Answer (score 0):

It was not clear, you do not have root password?
If you install Skype, I advise to download directly from the site http://www.skype.com/pt-br/download-skype/skype-for-computer/
You will download the .deb file
By downloading run in the terminal: dpkg -i (downloaded package).
Then run: apt-get -f install
So resolve the pending package.

Comment: I do not know what teh pass word is, nothing works. I changed one pass word and it works but not the root pass word.